# No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured error in cognito identity .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I implement Identity SDK cognito service as you can see:

```
public interface ICognitoService
{

    public Task<bool> SignUpAsync(string userName, string password, string email);

}
public class CognitoService : ICognitoService
{
    private readonly IAmazonCognitoIdentityProvider _cognitoService;
    string UserPoolId = "***";
    string AppClientId = "***";
    string ClientSecret = "c****";
    public CognitoService(IAmazonCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoService)
    {
        _cognitoService = cognitoService;
        var region = RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1;
        var userPoolId = "***";

        _cognitoService = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(region);
    }

 
    public async Task<bool> SignUpAsync(string userName, string password, string email)
    {
        var userAttrs = new AttributeType
        {
            Name = "email",
            Value = email,
        };

        var userAttrsList = new List<AttributeType>();

        userAttrsList.Add(userAttrs);

        var signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest
        {
            UserAttributes = userAttrsList,
            Username = userName,
            ClientId = AppClientId,
            Password = password
        };

        var response = await _cognitoService.SignUpAsync(signUpRequest);
        return response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

I register the service like this:

```
builder.Services.AddCognitoIdentity();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICognitoService, CognitoService>();
```

But When I call the service:

```
 var q = _cognitoService.SignUpAsync("esiak", "qqq@", "azx@gmail.com");
```

I get this error

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

 ---> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

   at Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.Validate()

   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor(AWSCredentials credentials, ClientConfig config)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.ClientFactory.CreateClient(Type serviceInterfaceType, AWSCredentials credentials, ClientConfig config)

   at Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.ClientFactory.CreateServiceClient(ILogger logger, Type serviceInterfaceType, AWSOptions options)

   at Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.ClientFactory.CreateServiceClient(IServiceProvider provider)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

   at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```